# Log On to symfony 1.4 application with Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have an application on Symfony 1.4 framework. Recently I've started building an app in Node.js.

I need to do some action's response in node and I'd like to set credientals (log In the user) remotely, because some data is dependent on the user's data and I can't omit it. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Nothing special yet. I'd rather ask more experienced developers, so I'm asking here. I've wanted send basic data like user and pass, but there's some hash needed..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understood your scenario, but from I grasp you could share the session data (if this is the "user data" the nodejs app needs) between the two platforms (maybe use a common database to store sessions, like Redis) or you could implement a web service or api (REST) to enable communication between the two platforms, if the data is more complex.
Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about REST API in app. Changing database would be another problem, because it's really big. I thought about creating new user called 'node' in my PHP app and log in by its data.